# How to register two DbContexts?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have two connections to database: MsSQL and MySQL. For mssql I do the following:

```
public class MssqlDbContext: DbContext
{

    public DbSet<ReportPhone> ReportPhones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReportPhoneDetail> ReportPhoneDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Operator> Operators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ReportPhoneConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CompanyPhoneConfiguration());
    }
}
```

and make DI in ioc container:

```
public static void WebConfigure(Container container)
{
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<DbContext, MssqlDbContext>();
    Configure(container);
}
```

how can i do the same for MysqlDbContext to?
for example:

```
public static void WebConfigure(Container container)
{
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<DbContext, MysqlDbContext>();
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<DbContext, MssqlDbContext>();
    Configure(container);
}
```

Comment: Just use concrete types: `container.RegisterPerWebRequest<MysqlDbContext, MysqlDbContext>();
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<MssqlDbContext, MssqlDbContext>();`

Comment: Are they the same data source and you want to use them interchangeably or are those two totally different data sources that you want to use at the same time?

Comment: This is two different data sources with different data.

Comment: What DI Container and version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

When you register the DbContext using:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<DbContext, MssqlDbContext>()
```

this *implies* that you want to inject it as a `DbContext` rather than the concrete type. In other words, using this approach, its consumers will have `DbContext` as a constructor argument, rather than `MssqlDbContext`.

When you have two different DbContext implementations, both with their seperate database schema, it doesn't make sense to inject a `DbContext`. That would be a [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) violation.

Depending on `DbContext` would be useless for the consumer, because it can't access its `ReportPhones` and `ReportPhoneDetails`. It can only do this by casting the `DbContext` back to `MssqlDbContext`, but that cumbersome and error prone: an incompatible `DbContext` implementation could have been injected.

So instead, you should let consumer depend on either `MssqlDbContext` or `MysqlDbContext` and use them directly. For instance:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MssqlDbContext context;

    public HomeController(MssqlDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // class members here
}
```

In your `WebConfigure` method, you should register the `DbContext` implementations using their concrete type:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<MysqlDbContext>();
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<MssqlDbContext>();
```

> **TIP**: Since both have a different schema, try coming up with a more functional name. `Mssql` and `Mysql` only describes the technology, not *what* is stored in those databases.